# Need to refresh pricing on a data grid update in xPages

Tags: datagrid, xpages

I have a data grid in an ordering system to represent all line items ordered.  There is a fair amount of calculations needed to determine the pricing.  I allow the user to edit an order and make changes to the QTY only on the data grid.  How do I program the changes to refresh the pricing on a different column other than the one being changed?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to refresh the whole thing you can string multiple partial refreshes together.  I googled for "XPages multiple partial refresh" or something and found this :

[How to do a partial refresh of multiple items in Xpages correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364137/how-to-do-a-partial-refresh-of-multiple-items-in-xpages-correctly)

Which basically points to an article from the late, great Tim Tripcony which is saved here : http://avatar.red-pill.mobi/tim/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-84B6VP

There are other examples out there as well.

Comment: Hi David.  Thanks for responding.  If I understand your answer, however, it looks like you're refreshing two distinct fields/links.  I am refreshing a datagrid with one call.  The datagrid columns and subsequent save to the record in the DB is all contained in one line.  The code to update all the changes in the datagrid is:  editedRowsArray = [-1];
var args = {
 onError: function() {alert('error - changes not saved'); }
}

restServiceObj.save(args);

restServiceObj.close();
gridObj._refresh();